# automatically check boxes in jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using a jquery accordion with a 1 check box in the header section  tag. Within the content area related to the header I have several elements that also contain check boxes.

If the check box is checked in the header element I would like to check all boxes in the content area for that header.

I know the Id of the header element which is "ui-accordion-accordion-header-0" and the content is aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-accordion-header-0" which corresponds to the id of the header.

Can someone point me in the direction for either a tutorial or example of how I can do this.

Comment: Post the HTML also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no HTML given, I tried to understand your problem assuming the html was something like this

```
input type="checkbox" id="ui-accordian-accordian-header-0"/>
<hr/>

<input type="checkbox" class="ui-accordian-accordian-header-0"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="ui-accordian-accordian-header-0"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="ui-accordian-accordian-header-0"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="ui-accordian-accordian-header-0"/>
```

Using the following code, you can check or uncheck all with the header checkbox

```
$("#ui-accordian-accordian-header-0").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var items = $("." + id);

    this.checked ? items.prop("checked", true) : items.prop("checked", false);
});
```

Heres a fiddle demoing the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/SeYqU/
This should be enough to get you on your way.

Comment: Thanks - works great and the fiddle helped me to understand the concept